# HTML to JSON using Java script

Tags: html, json, jsp

Please help me writing JSP script to post JSON to an API server.

I have a HTML page as below:

```html
<body>
<h2>Form</h2>
<form action="/endpoints" method="post" enctype='application/json'>
First Name:<input type="text" name="mac" size="12"/> 

<br/>Select Catagory:<br/>
<select name="catagory">
<option value="SmartDevice">SmartDevice</option>
<option value="Printer">Printer</option>
<option value="Scanner">Scanner</option>
</select>
<br/>Select Family:<br/>
<select name="family">
<option value="Android">Android</option>
<option value="Ricoh">Ricoh</option>
<option value="Canon">Canon</option>
</select>
<br/>Name:<br/>
<select name="name">
<option value="Android">Android</option>
<option value="Ricoh Multifunction Printer">Ricoh Multifunction Printer</option>
<option value="Canon Printer">Canon Printer</option>
</select>
<p>
<input type="submit" />
</p>
</form>
</body>
```

On click on submit, I would like to post the below JSON output to the local API server.

```html
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/endpoints  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '[{"mac": ["aabbccddeeff", "bbccddeeffaa"], "device": {"category": "Printer", "family": "Xerox", "name": "Xerox WorkCenter"}}]'
```

Please suggest JSP script to convert the above HTML to JSON and post it to the server.

Comment: I am able to get the value using the below script and assign it a variable, but I do not know how to convert that to JSON output.
<br>
var nam = document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value
var famil = document.getElementsByName("family")[0].value
var catagor = document.getElementsByName("catagory")[0].value
var address = document.getElementsByName("mac")[0].value

Comment: Why not try to use JSON.stringify()?